# Debugging JavaScript using emulator for wp7

Tags: javascript, debugging, windows-phone-7

Hey guys i have a problem debugging my Mobile app for WP7.
my javascript is in another .js file. now i have even put the debugger; in the code but it completely ignores the line of coding, and i cant put in breakpoints in aswell as soon as i run the breakpoints become a litttle circle saying , images follows :

[image]

would really like some help, the company wants to see results, but i cant finish it because of debuggin? any help or links will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging Javascript embedded in an app is not supported by the Windows Phone SDK.

The best you can do to debug your Javascript code is to use the **Desktop** version of Internet Explorer 9, as it shares the same basecode as WP7's IE and WebBrowser control.

Comment: cool thanks allot for this information. but i dont understand how one can debug the Javascript in IE9 ? very new to web/mobile development.

Comment: Press F12 to open the Developper Tools. There you will be able to inspect the DOM, debug Javascript, etc. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507(VS.85).aspx

Comment: so i dont run the code through the emulator? or do i just run the .js file in ie9? sorry for stupid questions just want clarity

Comment: No, running the code through the emulator is useless for debugging. Create an HTML page, add a reference to your Javascript and debug it with the IE Developper Tools